# How can I set a include of an actionbar, for example, invisible?

Tags: android

I made a layout for an actionbar:

**actionbar.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:height="70dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mobility" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I included this layout in some other layouts like this:

```
 <include
  android:id="@+id/include"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  layout="@layout/actionbar" />
```

And now I want to set this included actionbar-layout invisible in all layout where I included it.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

And consider I use ViewFlipper to switch between the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
findViewById(R.id.titleLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

In case you are using ViewFlipper, then something like this might help:

```
vf.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.titleLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

where vf is the reference to your ViewFlipper from xml

HTH

Comment: es I tried this and it works for the first layout. Because I use ViewFlipper to switch between views and if I use the code you wrote it gets only in the "Main View", where I declared the ViewFlipper, invisible. So I want to make this include in all layout invisible. Any idea?

Comment: No it doesn't work either. I think I have to set all include seperatly. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it invisible like any other element or a layout:

```
findViewById(R.id.include).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Two remarks:

- I think you're actually looking for the stronger form of invisibility which is: `findViewById(R.id.include).setVisibility(View.GONE);`
- You must use different id's for each include to ensure, that the right one is found. But I guess you just simplified the code for your question.

Comment: yes I tried this and it works for the first layout. Because I use ViewFlipper to switch between views and if I use the code you wrote it gets only in the "Main View", where I declared the ViewFlipper, invisible. So I want to make this include in all layout invisible. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have more then one ActionBar? What API-Level you're using? You're either on a newer API-Level (Android 3.0+) and able to use Fragments and ActionBar (no ViewFlipper) or an older API-Level (Android 2.3-) and must use ViewFlipper and ActionBarSherlock. In the second case you must set all includes invisible seperately.

Comment: I'm programming on version 4.0.3 and minSdkVersion 14.

Comment: In this case you should definitely use Fragments. ViewFlipper was a good idea before Android 3.0, but it consumes a lot CPU and therefore battery. The easiest way to get into Fragments and a number of screens in parallel and ActionBar and all together is by adding a new Activity in Eclipse, choose the navigation and let it build the skeleton. Eclipse: new -> Android Activity -> Blank Activity -> Navigation Type: Scrollable Tabs and wipe

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Good knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
View mView = findViewById(R.id.include);
ImageView mImgView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Using that approach, you can access any field in any include you have.

Comment: Error: cannot cast from void to ImageView.

Comment: make clean to project